# Configure two Fiori tiles target same application but each displaying different view

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-business-technology-platform

I have created a custom Fiori application and deployed it to ABAP repository. Now I have to create two tiles.

1. One for displaying the record.
2. Another one for creating the new record.

Both the pages(display and new) are created in different views in same application.

Can I set the first page in first tile and second page in second tile as home page while launching, without creating the same copy of project again?

Comment: You can consider a parameter on the URL so that the tiles have a different URL, although the same app.
Note that the SAP Fiori Design Guidelines state that Display and Edit should have the same(!) URL. 
The draft state of the object linked to determines whether edit or display mode is to be shown.

Comment: @SAPFioriCrew Thanks for the information,can you please tell how to dynamically set the initial view based on the url parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to have 2 differents target mapping parameters on the tiles and use `this.getOwnerComponent().getComponentData().startupParameters` to retrieve them.
This way you can read the parameter and choose what to do.
However as suggested by user6177399 the guidelines for edit and display view would not suggest that.